# Wobbling sound from wheels at all speeds

Tags: tires, wheels

I had a wobbling sensation while braking, and they replaced my front brakes and said the rotors were warped and replaced those, too.  Wobbling went away.

Then I had my tires rotated for 50,000 mile maintenance, and a new slight wobbling sound appeared, which doesn't seem related to the brakes this time.  I looked at the wheels and noticed screws in two of them, so I had those removed, but it didn't fix the sound.  I then had the wheels balanced, but that didn't fix it either.

Sound clips:

https://clyp.it/ejkehkps

https://clyp.it/3u3e3unx

2016 Toyota Corolla LE.

- 2 front tires are originals, from 49th week of 2015 = 2015-12
- 2 rear tires were made in 24th week of 2017 = 2017-06

Comment: How many miles on the tires? Which are front and which are back tires?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Well the front are original, so 50k.  The rear are half as old, so probably 25k.

Comment: The reason I asked was, when you bring the rear tires up to the front (during a rotation) with a little different wear pattern than you are used to, it will cause there to be a bit of a vibration and possibly noise. Older tires will tend to make more noise than newer tires, due to there being less rubber, which will insulate the vehicle (to an extent). The shorter the tread gets, the noisier it will be. Some tires are more susceptible to this than others.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 If I'm hearing something repetitive, then the wear is asymmetrical, though, right?

Comment: Is the noise more prevalent at any given corner of the car? (I finally got a chance to listen to the noise, and understand your statement.)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm not sure where it's coming from

Comment: Favorited because I think I have the same problem. 4 new tires installed 2 years ago, they now have 28k miles on them with about 8/32" left. I rarely rotate but I think I've noticed more noise after rotating them several months ago and it hasn't gone away.

Comment: Took it to another mechanic, they said the tires are "cut up" and that's why it's making noise, and it needs an alignment, but nothing serious is wrong with them? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯